# How to to postpone the cron execution for next few hours

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I have to restart my system daily for this I have created a script file. In that script file I have added condition that if downloading or uploading is going on then skip that restart.

Here is my script file

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$Upload" ]; then
    echo itsme | sudo -S shutdown -r now
fi
```

and for executing this script file I have written a cron job as

```
0 12 * * * ${HOME}/reboot-me.sh
```

Now I have to add functionality as is downloading or uploading is going on then postpone the restart for next 1 hour or add delay of 1 hour.

So How can I postpone this job?

**Edit**
I have edited my condition is this work?

```
if [ "$Upload" ]; then
        echo itsme | sudo -S shutdown -r now
else
        sleep 3600
        if [ "$Upload" ]; then
           echo itsme | sudo -S shutdown -r now
        else
           echo "uploading....."
        fi
fi
```

Comment: what about a `sleep 3600`?

Comment: one quick question, I am executing script once in a day if I added sleep 3600 in my script did I have to again run that script or it will continue after 1 hour.

Comment: It should continue after 1 hour. Note that `sleep` is like a "pause" and once the time is over, it resumes the execution.

Comment: Yes, it should work. Note this would postpone once and then restart; if it is uploading again after one hour, it would not restart. If you really want to restart after an upload happened, any time, you can consider using a `while true; do ... done` with conditions inside.

Answer (score 0):

Let your cronjob run every hour and check if its time for a reboot:

- past 12 o'clock?
- already rebooted today?
- something running that should postpone a reboot?

With these 3 points you should be able to decide if you can reboot the machine or not.